# static char* vs static char[] memory access

Tags: c++

I'm making a bit of C code compile as C++ and have come across something that's puzzling me. Consider the following function taken from LuaFileSystem.

```
static const char *perm2string (unsigned short mode) {
  static char perms[10] = "---------";
  //static char* perms = "---------";
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<9;i++) perms[i]='-';
  if (mode  & _S_IREAD)
   { perms[0] = 'r'; perms[3] = 'r'; perms[6] = 'r'; }
  if (mode  & _S_IWRITE)
   { perms[1] = 'w'; perms[4] = 'w'; perms[7] = 'w'; }
  if (mode  & _S_IEXEC)
   { perms[2] = 'x'; perms[5] = 'x'; perms[8] = 'x'; }
  return perms;
}
```

This code will work correctly, however if I uncomment the commented line, it crashes. I've stepped over this with a debugger and it seems that with `static char* perms` the string is placed in read-only memory and so the first loop will cause an access violation, using the static array causes no such issues. I'm curious as to why this is happening when the string isn't declared const.

Comment: `"---------"` is a _string literal_. It's a _static array of 10 **const** chars_ (the 9 '-' plus the "null terminator"), it's _immutable_. You can get a pointer to its first char with `const char* p = "---------";` but if you want to modify it you must copy it into a separate array (`perms` in your example).

Comment: > This code will work correctly... 

until you use it concurrently. When multiple threads try to access that static character string/array, you will get strange behaviors. Since your code has only 8 different conditions, you could very well use a switch/case lookup and return a predefined string literal for each: `switch (mode) { case 0 : return "---------"; case _S_IREAD : return "r--r--r--"; /* etc... */ }` That way the function is read only, threadsafe, and probably faster than the char array fiddling you do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right.

String literals are *immutable*, and `"---------"` is a string literal. Your `static char*` points to that string literal.

The immutability is not inherently enforced at compile-time, so when you try to write to the literal, you get *undefined behaviour* instead. This may result in a runtime crash.

> `[C++11: 2.14.5/12]:` Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation-defined. **The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.**

C++ actually requires that this pointer be a `static char const*`, though some compilers only *warn* about that.

**However**, initialising an *array* with a string literal will *copy* the string. The array is your own, to do with as you please. That's why you can modify the `static char[10]` without a crash.

> `[C++11: 8.5.2/1]:` A char array (whether plain `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`), `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow character literal, `char16_t` string literal, `char32_t` string literal, or wide string literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces. **Successive characters of the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array.**

Comment: Thanks for the spec quotes, I guess I was relying on the compiler to warn me about this (MSVC2010 doesn't even give me a warning with -Wall set)

Comment: @user1520427: `-Wall` is more like `-Wsome`. Use `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`, too (for GCC; not sure about VS)

Comment: @Shahbaz: What's "dirty" about using the Stack Overflow _edit_ function to improve my answer and add value for the OP? I _wasn't_ the first answer; in fact, I was only six seconds ahead of yours. Please check your facts before throwing around vicious accusations. And are you suggesting that, at 82k, I should be forced to stop playing?

Comment: You played dirty and got two upvotes? You are a terrible dirty player.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Does my evil know no bounds?

Comment: It's dirty because he's losing!!!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I've been around to know how SO works. Simple questions like this get a large view in very small time. Small but fast one line answers often get a few up votes before they know it. Then good answers appear and get higher votes in the end. So intentionally, one can write a quick answer, absorb the initial upvotes, then incrementally improve the answer very quickly so it wouldn't stay behind the competitors.

Comment: I call that dirty a trick. Because right from the beginning, you know that you're going to make references to the standard and make a complete explanation. Why not write the whole thing and then click answer? Because you know that by this "dirty trick" you eventually get higher votes. And no, you're not evil, but I just don't understand why you are going all that way for more rep when you already have so much. @ScottW, like I care. I rarely even answer these simple questions.

Comment: Guys you're arguing about _points_ on a duplicate question. Move on? (or `goto` Meta)

Comment: @Shahbaz: You have the same number of upvotes that I do. I got no significant rep from this answer, and I didn't post it to get rep. What's the problem? Move on.

Answer (score 3):

When you write the following:

```
const char *X = "...."
```

You have `"...."` in read-only memory and `X` pointing to it. In fact, type of `X` should be `const char *`, not just `char *`.

On the other hand, when you write:

```
char X[] = "...."
```

This is equivalent to:

```
char X[] = {'.', '.', '.', '.', '\0'}
```

which is an array initializer. In other words, `X` would be an array (not a pointer) and it would contain the contents of `"...."`. Since it's not `const`, you can change it without problem.

Comment: Was there something wrong with my answer? I'd appreciate feedback from the down-vote giver.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are `const char *`. You are not allowed to modify them in C++ or C.

For legacy reasons they can be converted to `char *`, however this does not make it legal to modify them.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are stored in read only section of memory. Any attempt to modify the contents of a string literal invokes Undefined Behaviour and segmentation fault on most implementations.
SO if you need to have a modifiable char array then declare it as `char perms[10]` instead of `char* perms`

Answer (score 0):

It's normal and nothing to do with c++ (you will have the same results with C). `static char* perms = "---------";` is const because `"---------"` is a part of your binary (you can see it with `objdump` programm)

Comment: Don't confuse `const`ness for immutability.

Answer (score 0):

`char* perms = "-----"` creates a pointer pointing to the string, which is located in a protected segment. Trying to write to it will cause a crash.

`char perms[] = "-----"` creates a character array on the stack and populates it with the relevant characters from "-----".

This is an example of arrays and pointers being inequivalent.